# E-mail duplicate validation

Tags: asp-classic

First of all what i am trying to do is link a access database to a site which was successful. Now I am trying to get a specific message to come up on a sign up page stating that the e-mail entered already exist,if it does, in place of the odbc error message that will usually appear if the e-mail exist, however I am getting my error message to appear weather it exist or not. 
The code i have done so far is shown below and insight on what might be wrong will be appreciated.

```
sql="INSERT INTO Customers (Customerfirstname, Customerlastname, Email, Password, Address,        Phoneno)     VALUES (' "&fname&"',' "&lname&"','"&email&"',' "&password&"',' "&caddress&"',' "&phno&"')"
on error resume next
  Con.Execute sql  
    if err.number <> 0 then
     response.write("E-mail already exist")         
    else  
  ' append the query string to the redirect URL
      If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
      If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
      Else
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
      End If
    End If
 end if
Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
con.close: set conn = nothing
```

Comment: Are you maintaining a legacy application? There's absolutely no good reason to use classic ASP on a new project. Also, Access is *not* a good database.

Comment: i am new to this...not sure what u mean by legacy application and the reason why i use access is because of familiarity

Comment: By legacy application, I mean something that's already existed for a long time and you're just maintaining. If you're writing a new application, don't use classic ASP. Use a modern web framework (like ASP .NET MVC), and use a real database like SQL Server. There's going to be a bigger learning curve, but it's worth it.

Comment: My phone number is 0'); UPDATE Customers SET PASSWORD = ''; --, and I just hacked your system. You need to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: Before you run your insert query, run a select query, someething like select count(id) as customercount from Customers where email = '"&email&"'.  If it returns a count of > 0 then display an email exists message, otherwise run the insert query.  I'm assuming you know how to do conditional statements in ASP/VBS

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform some validation before trying to INSERT anything to your database.

First up, grab the email address they submitted via your form and after having cleansed it for injection (as mentioned here) then run a SELECT query to see if the address exists.

If it does exist, redirect them to a nice error page, if it doesn't exist and once you've cleaned the rest of the user submission only then should INSERT in to your database.

Also, using "if err.number <> 0 then response.write("E-mail already exist")" is bad. What if the email address does not exist but maybe they tried inserting too long a string to your db? Or what if the DB is unavailable for some reason? You'll be giving them the wrong error.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the actual error is:

```
if err.number <> 0 then
     response.write(err.description)         
else
..
```